# How to skip the empty space before and after the limits of the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below:

```
Year<-c("2015","2016","2017")
Total<-c(60,70,80)
key=c(1,2,3)
df<-data.frame(Year,Total,key)
levs<-c("2015","2016","2017")
df$Year <- factor(df$Year, levels = levs)
```

and I want to create a line chart with specific limits on x axis (from 2015 to 2017). The same logic should follow the range slider even thias is not a priority. My code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ggplotly(ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = Total, key = key, text = paste('Year:', Year, '<br>Total headcount:', Total))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("2015", "2016", "2017"))  + 
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), colour="#00A0BD")  + 
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Total Headcount") + 
  ylim(0, 80), tooltip = "text") %>%
rangeslider(#start = "2015", end = "2017"
)
```

Even when Im using `scale_x_discrete(limits=c("2015", "2016", "2017"))` the limits are not the requested. Here is the plot with the empty space at the end and at the beginning even without the range slider.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing what you're finding problematic is the space on the left and the right of the data. That is caused by `rangeslider`; it has nothing to do with `scale_x_discrete()` which you don't need (but is working as expected, for example test by removing "2015").

Comment: I added a photo. Even without the range slider it is not correct.

Comment: I editted the title in order to make the Q more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.95:3.05), expand = FALSE)` and `rangeslider(start = 0.95, end = 3.05)`

```
ggplotly(ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = Total, key = key, text = paste('Year:', Year, '<br>Total headcount:', Total))) +
       scale_x_discrete(limits=c("2015","2016","2017"))  + 
       coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.95:3.05), expand = FALSE)+
       geom_line(aes(group = 1), colour="#00A0BD")  + 
       xlab("Year") + ylab("Total Headcount") + 
       ylim(0, 80), tooltip = "text") %>%
rangeslider(start = 0.95, end = 3.05)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so key was the issue.

Comment: Actually, that's just a coincidence